# Impact of deleting upstream GitHub repository of my fork

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I've forked a repository on GitHub.

If the owner of the upstream repository decided to delete their repository, will my fork still survive or be deleted too?

Github Enterprise Help documentation seems to suggest when a repository is deleted, all forks are too. However, does that apply to non-enterprise GitHub accounts too?

What comes to mind for me is MySQL and the MariaDB "fork". Is this actually a "fork" in the GitHub meaning, or is it merely a copy (so it appears as an original codebase) so that if Oracle were to remove MySQL, MariaDB wouldn't be impacted? How do they then keeping sync with MySQL new features.. manually?

Answer (score 1):

The thing with git is that it is a distributed system. There is no need for any central repository at all. As soon as you have forked a repo it is in a sense completely detached from the source. You can change this or even push it to a different remote without the original source ever knowing.

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Comment: I don't think it's completely detached, is it? When I look at repo's on GitHub, I can see everyone who's forked it. For example, here's all the forks of MySQL: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/network/members

Comment: The problem, of course, is that jimmy is talking aobut git and Turgs is talking about github. Note that "fork" is not really a git concept (though it is a concept of just about every git repo hosting site I can think of). A clone is fully independent of its source; it starts out with a remote config that points to the source, but this can be deleted with no ill effects; and the source knows nothing of the clone. How this works with forks depends on how the hosting site implements forks...

Comment: ... Now I doubt any major hosting site allows one user's action to delete another user's repo, whether it's a fork or not. If I found one that did, I would make sure to never use that host.  But if you're worried, you can always just make a local clone of the fork, then push it as an independent project back to the host (which will then no longer have any way to see the "new" project as connected to the original).